How powerful are sequences of Steiner symmetrizations?
I was studying geometric analysis and have encountered something called Steiner symmetrization method. Intuitively I understand how it's made to be applied and used, but Wikipedia pages do not give any details on it. In order to prove the Riesz rearrangement inequality I have proved that for any subset $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ of finite Lebesgue measure there exists a sequence of Steiner symmetrizations that "transform" the set into a ball of the same volume (details later). I have found a proof of isoperimetric inequality online that requires a stronger sense of convergence to the ball and that is more complicated than my construction, but it still proves a statement of the form:

For each shape $X$, there is a sequence $S$ such that $T(X,S)$ is satisfied. ($T$ is some statement)

Only the existance of $S$ is proved, we know nothing about how it looks. I understand that this is completely sufficient for these theorems, but intuitively I believe that most sequences satisfy the condition we want. Intuitively, the more random the sequence is, the better it approximates the ball. An example would be making a snowball. Each time we grab it with a random angle and we symmetrically press it with our hands from opposite sides. After few random angles, the pile of snow is a (snow)ball. And we are sure to make a ball $\Rightarrow$ almost all sequences do the job. Has this intuition been formalized in a statement of the form:

Any (or almost any) sequence $S$ that satisfies a condition $C$ and any (or almost any) shape $X$ satisfy $T(X,S)?$

Is there a theorem of this form? This is unnecessarily strong, but closer to the human intuition.
$\;$
$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$Details and an example:
Under a symmetrization in the direction of $p\in\mathbb{R}P^{n-1}$ of the shape $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ of finite Lebesgue measure I assume a set $S_p(X)$ such that $X\cap q$ and $S_p(X)\cap q$ have the same length for any line $q$ parallel to $p$ and $S_p(X)$ is symmetrical over the hyperplane $p^\perp$.
Under a transformation of a shape $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ of finite Lebesgue measure under a sequence of symmetrizations $S=(S_{p_1},S_{p_2},\ldots)$, I assume the limit of the sequence of shapes $X_0:=X$, $X_k:=S_{p_k}(X_{k-1})$ for $k\geq1$ (if it exists). The limit is taken in the metric $d(X,Y):=\mu(X\triangle Y)$ ($\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and $\triangle$ is the symmetric difference of sets). Let's denote this limit by $F(X,S).$
Example of my conjecture:

For (almost) any sequence $S=(S_{p_1},S_{p_2},\ldots)$ of symmetrizations that satisfies a condition $C$ and (almost) any shape $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ of finite Lebesgue measure $F(X,S)$ exists.

Condition $C$ could be for example that the sequence $S$ contains only finitely many different directions or that the angle of consecutive directions $p_k$ and $p_{k+1}$ is a constant. It could also be that $S$ is generated in some random process. All these examples of $C$ give sequences that are easy to imagine.

In case you didn't know them, the following articles prove convergence of sets to the ball under random Steiner symmetrizations:
Mani-Levitska, P.: Random Steiner symmetrizations. Stud. Sci. Math. Hung. 21(3–4), 373–378 (1986)
A. VOLCIC, Random Steiner symmetrizations of sets and functions, Calc. Var. Partial Differential Equations 46 (2013), no. 3-4, 555-569.

@SaúlRM Thank you! I definitely didn't know about this.
